# Angular filter generating escaped HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

This filter is operating on a field that's being loaded from a REST service. It's converting new line characters to `<br/>` tags and they're getting escaped.

```
angular.module('myMod').filter('convertBreaks', function($sce) {
    return function(input) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input.replace(/[\n]/g, "<br/>"));
    };
});
```

It's called like this:

```
<p>{{data.x.y.z | convertBreaks}}</p>
```

The `<br/>` tags are coming out escaped. Any suggestions why?

**Update**

Forgot to mention that this is being executed by a directive that uses the $compile service.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
<p ng-bind-html="data.x.y.z | convertBreaks"></p>
```

Angular has some built in security mechanisms that will cause those kinds of shenanigans.

Comment: How would I make this work with a directive that uses $compile?